# Property Availability Calender Widget

Tags: javascript, html, web, calendar, widget

I am developing a website for a client who is renting out their home.

They would like to be able to login to a dashboard and set individual days to available and not available (to rent out), this could be achieved by choosing a color to set the day to.

The client's customers can view on the site a grid of the month with different colored days (and select other months).

Is there a simple way to achieve this? I have tried Google Calendar but I have found it too sophisticated to handle this in a basic way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found this while looking at other sites: http://www.availcheck.com/

Seems to do the trick although does charge!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Javascript, this calendar is great and has a good documentation.

[Javascript Full Calendar](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/)

Answer (score 0):

Check out DayPilot. It originally started as an ASP.Net Calendar, but it looks like they have a client-side Javascript version also. It's been very well maintained and the code is clean and works like a charm.

[DayPilot for JavaScript:](http://javascript.daypilot.org/scheduler/)

[image]

If you don't wanna pay, or need to customize the code, then there is a [Daypilot-lite -- Open source and free version.](http://javascript.daypilot.org/lite/)